# Random phases postulate in quantum statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

Quantum statistical mechanics has two postulates, namely 
i) Assumption of equal a priori equilibrium probabilities
ii)Independent random phases

The first postulate is in accordance with classical statistical physics, yet the second postulate is purely quantum mechanical consideration.

What is the motivation to take this postulate and its implication?

Comment: It is actually the ergodicity assumption, which is equally present in the classical stat.mech: one assumes that the trajectory of the system will cover all the phase space (for given energy) and replaces it by many independent systems.